# Sky segmentation data set or model for deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, images

## Context

I am searching an open data set and/or a model "ready" (or close to be ready) to segment the sky out of outdoor images, e.g.:

Input:

[image: Pascal Debrunner Oeschinen Lake, Kandersteg, Switzerland]

*Source; unsplash, Pascal Debrunner, Oeschinen Lake, Kandersteg, Switzerland*

Desired output:

[image: Desired output]

## Question

Do you know some data sets or models on that topic?
Or better, meta-surveys on that question?

Info; the deep-learning backend will normally be tensorflow/keras based.

Comment: I wonder the Title of the question and questions inside the body seem to be different..!!

Comment: Indeed, but instead of a suite of Answers on specific data sets (which would be fine), if someone passing here knows a meta survey on that topic, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

[Sky Dataset](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Eeduardob/datasets/sky/)

A Dataset for Sky Segmentation

The Sky dataset contains a collection of 60 images with ground truth for sky segmentation. It was based on the Caltech Airplanes Side dataset by R. Fergus 15/02/03. Those images from the dataset which contained sky regions were selected and ground truths were created for them. The original dataset image names were kept unchanged.

[image]

The dataset can be [downloaded here](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Eeduardob/datasets/sky/sky.zip).

---

A large dataset of webcam images annotated with sky regions.

[Download Here](http://mvrl.cs.uky.edu/datasets/skyfinder/)

**[Useful Resource](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322076297_Segmenting_Sky_Pixels_in_Images)**

Comment: 60K images you mean?

Comment: No, it's just 60 images